# $\mathrm{Hom}$-sets in categories with finite biproducts have the structure of a commutative monoid: a reference for a proof

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, additive-categories

It seems it is a folk result that $\mathrm{Hom}$-sets in categories with finite biproducts (including the empty biproduct) have the structure of a commutative monoid. I know an analogous result for abelian categories from Boceux' book, but the proof presented there doesn't appear to be generalizable for this case. Does anybody have a reference? Or, perhaps, if someone knows the proof, they can help providing it?

The idea is that, for morphisms $f,g\colon X\to Y$, take $f + g$ to be $(f, g)\circ \Delta$ or $\Delta\circ h$ where $h\colon X\to Y\oplus Y$ is the morphism induced by the universal property of a product. But I struggle to make sense of details.

Comment: I first learned this from Hilton & Stammbach, which I still find rather readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a fairly detailed proof in my blog post *[A meditation on semiadditive categories](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/)*. The sketch is that

1. In any category with finite coproducts, every object is uniquely and hence canonically a commutative monoid with respect to the coproduct, with multiplication given by the codiagonal $\nabla : X + X \to X$; dually, in any category with finite products, every object is uniquely and hence canonically a cocommutative comonoid with respect to the product, with comultiplication given by the diagonal $\Delta : X \to X \times X$, and
2. In a category with finite biproducts, finite products and finite coproducts agree, so every object is uniquely and hence canonically a commutative monoid with  respect to the *product*, and this commutative monoid structure passes to homsets.

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, your post is well-written, but I can't see why the commutative monoid structure passes to homsets. You say that, e.g., associativity follows from associtivity and coassociativity of the monoid with respect to biproduct, but how so? I would be really thankful if you could expand on this.

Comment: @Jxt921: this is a general fact about algebraic structures with respect to the cartesian product; you repeatedly use the fact that hom preserves limits (and in particular finite products) in the second argument.